# Rails locale not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using Rails 4
I have set the default locale to is in config/application.rb
is.yml is in config/locales
In Rails console I type

```
I18n.available_locales  
=> [:en, :is]  

I18n.default_locale  
=> :is  

I18n.locale  
=> :is  

a = 1.25  
number_with_precision(a, locale: :is)  
=> "1.250"
```

This is just the en format
Was expecting 1,25

is.yml file below:

```
is:  
  number:  
    format:  
      delimiter: ! ','  
      precision: 3  
      separator: .  
      significant: false  
      strip_insignificant_zeros: false
```

Any suggestions on how to get this working?

Answer (score 2):

`1.250` is exactly what you should get with your settings. To get `1,25` this will work.

```
format:
  delimiter: ! ','
  precision: 2
  separator: ','
  significant: false
  strip_insignificant_zeros: false
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It solves the problem with the separator. Now we get as you suggest 1,25. But if I have a number 2222,22 the Delimeter is not showing. I have set the delimeter to .  but the number_with_precision helper uses "" as a default so no delimeter is loaded. Does anyone know how to get the number_with_precision helper to load and use the delimeter value in the yml file?

Comment: @iceman  The same does not seem to be working while translating from french to english. I have posted the question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34739761/localization-of-number-from-french-locale-to-english-locale-not-working-in-rails). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can create your default configuration of delimiter on locale. Like:

```
en:
  format:
    number:
      delimiter: ','


pt-BR:
  format:
    number:
      delimiter: '.'
```

After you set up this. You can call locale on normal delimiter like:

for pt-BR:

```
number_with_precision(6419336, precision: 2, delimiter: 
I18n.t('number.format.delimiter')) #=> "6,419,336.00"
```

for en:

```
number_with_precision(6419336, precision: 2, delimiter: 
I18n.t('number.format.delimiter')) #=> "6.419.336,00"
```