# Localization of number from french locale to english locale not working in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, localization

As we know french numbers use "," as decimal separators as compared to english.

eg: English : 10.25% is
    French : 10,25%

I am able to successfully translate english numbers to french:

```
number_with_precision(121.45, locale: :fr)
#=> 121,45
```

But I am not able to translate french numbers to english:

```
number = number_with_precision(121.45, locale: :fr)
number #=> 121,45
number = number_with_precision(number, locale: :en)
number #=> 121,45
```

The number remains in french locale.

This is my en.yml:

```
en:
  number:
    format:
      delimiter: ! ','
      separator: '.'
      significant: false
      strip_insignificant_zeros: false
```

this is my fr.yml:

```
fr:
  number:
    format:
      delimiter: ! ','
      separator: ','
      significant: false
      strip_insignificant_zeros: false
```

Is there a mistake in my translation file which is causing this?

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing with what you consider as "English to French" is not "from English". `121.45` is a Ruby numeric literal, and is neither English nor French (although the literal itself uses a period for decimals like in the English notation although it uses underscore for delimiter, unlike English, which uses the comma).

In what you called "French to English", you are passing a string in French format. That is why it does not work. How is `number_with_precision` supposed to know that the string passed is written in French notation?

Comment: i understand what you are saying. How is this supposed to be handled in that case? If i get number string in french, is there a inbuilt rails way to convert it to english format?

Comment: I am not sure how you do that in Rails, but the twitter-cldr gem is good for that.